# Buy One get 50% Off

Tags: discount, coupon, coupon-codes

I've been reading up on how to implement the promotion "Buy One, get your second item 50% off" 
But am having no luck with this or anyone's answer. Is this possible in Magento 1.9?
Can anyone help? Would be so grateful!